# Sitecore pipeline processor messing up the CMS

Tags: sitecore, pipeline, processor

I have a pipeline processor which works as expected on the site, but causes havoc when you go in to the CMS.

What is the proper way to determine if the request is to the CMS?
Preferably I'd like something a little more robust than checking to see if the URL contains "/sitecore/".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Site context is a great way to do this. You can use standard Sitecore configuration factory approaches to feed in the site names that should utilize the extension, then ignore others, including "shell."

c.f. https://community.sitecore.net/technical_blogs/b/sitecorejohn_blog/posts/the-sitecore-asp-net-cms-configuration-factory

Answer (score 3):

You can exit gracefully if you are in the "shell" site...

```csharp
if (Sitecore.Context.Site.Name.Equals("shell", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
{
    // Exit here if we're avoiding the sitecore shell altogether
    return;
}
```

It depends on what it is about the circumstances that is causing your code to blow up. You can check the page mode to avoid problem modes...

```csharp
if (Sitecore.Context.PageMode.IsPageEditorEditing)
{
    // Exit here if we're avoiding someone editing the page.
    return;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This is a good answer. Clearly the key to identify if the context site is "Shell". To be honest I hadn't realised the CMS ran as this site.

Comment: I'm choosing the previous answer as the accepted one because it's more configurable, but both work perfectly for my purposes.